# Detect paired nested macros

Tags: macros, math-operators, white-space

I created a macro that automatically detects if `\dif`, defined as

```
\newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm{d}}
```

delimits an integral and in this case a small space between the argument of the integral and `\dif` is added. The macro is given by the following code

```
\makeatletter
\let\originalint\int
\def\int@arg{b}
\renewcommand\int{\@ifstar\originalint{\expandafter\myint}}
\def\myint{\let\int@opt\@empty\def\int@op{\originalint}%
    \int@test@opt}
\def\int@test@opt{\@ifnextchar[\int@option{\int@test}}
\def\int@option[#1]{\def\int@opt{#1}\int@test}
\def\int@test{\@ifnextchar\limits\int@catchlimits{\@ifnextchar_\int@catchsub{\@ifnextchar^\int@catchsup{\int@print}}}}
\def\int@catchlimits\limits{\expandafter\def\expandafter\int@op\expandafter{\int@op\limits}\int@test}
\def\int@catchsub_#1{\expandafter\def\expandafter\int@op\expandafter{\int@op_{#1}}\int@test}
\def\int@catchsup^#1{\expandafter\def\expandafter\int@op\expandafter{\int@op^{#1}}\int@test}
\def\int@print#1\dif#2{%
        \ifx\int@opt\@empty%
            \int@op%
        \else%
            \ifx\int@opt\int@arg%
                \expandafter\smashoperator\expandafter{\int@op}%
            \else%
                \expandafter\smashoperator\expandafter[\expandafter\int@opt\expandafter]\expandafter{\int@op}%
            \fi%
        \fi%
        #1 \, \dif #2   
}
\makeatother
```

The problem occurs when there are nested integrals, for example

```
\begin{equation}
\int_1^{10} \int_{\{u = t\}} \vert\nabla u \vert \dif \sigma \dif t
\end{equation}
```

In this case, the code produces the following output

[image]

with a double space before `\dif \sigma` and no space before `\dif t`. An obvious workaround is to group the inner integral

```
\begin{equation}
\int_1^{10} {\int_{\{u = t\}} \vert\nabla u \vert \dif \sigma} \dif t
\end{equation}
```

Is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: this code seems far more complicated than needed, `\let\int@opt\@empty\def\int@op{\originalint}%` is `\def\int@op{\originalint}%` and `\ifx\int@opt\@empty
            \int@op
        \else` is `\ifx\int@opt\@empty\else` (none of the `%` are needed) why the expandafter in `\expandafter\smashoperator\expandafter{\int@op}` ?

Comment: It seems to be like typical LaTeX macros. There are lines 1-25 and all these lines are 1) strange, 2) irrelevant:).

Comment: Ok for the %, but without the expandafter `\smashoperator` does not work.

Comment: @LucaBenatti that would be very odd, but as you have not shown any definition, can't really comment (nor can we run or debug your code)

Comment: Your code with `\dif` as delimiter is very fragile. But the syntax is very complicated, as far as I can see. I'd simply define `\sint` for the `\smashoperator` version. And I'd not use `\dif` as a delimiter, but use `\dif` defined as `\mathop{}\!d` (or `\mathrm{d}`). Much simpler and more robust.

Comment: My opinion: OP seems to be on the side of "maximize interface convenience, regardless of implementation difficulty", while most of the experienced LaTeX users are on the side of "maximize (interface convenience + implementation simplicity)". Suggesting these people to do it the latter way tend to not work very well, but alternative approaches will be useful for future visitors.

Comment: @wipet To be fair, LaTeX macros are complex, but are no more complex than necessary to implement the features it need to implement. (as far as I can see. Do you have a specific counter example?), while for the OP in this case there appears to be some unnecessary complication (e.g. seemingly redundant expandafter before `\smashoperator`, `\let\int@opt\@empty` (OP doesn't clarify what feature is desired, but the best one I can guess is that it tries to make sure that) if there's a `\int_\dif ... \dif x` where the first one is unbraced then the first `\dif` would not be erroneously caught

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps wrapping the tokens `\dif` delivered by your macro-mechanism into `\@firstofone{...}` and thus hiding them from macros that process `\dif`-delimited arguments does the trick?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm{d}}

\makeatletter
\let\originalint\int
\def\int@arg{b}
\renewcommand\int{\@ifstar\originalint{\expandafter\myint}}
\def\myint{\let\int@opt\@empty\def\int@op{\originalint}%
    \int@test@opt}
\def\int@test@opt{\@ifnextchar[\int@option{\int@test}}
\def\int@option[#1]{\def\int@opt{#1}\int@test}
\def\int@test{\@ifnextchar\limits\int@catchlimits{\@ifnextchar_\int@catchsub{\@ifnextchar^\int@catchsup{\int@print}}}}
\def\int@catchlimits\limits{\expandafter\def\expandafter\int@op\expandafter{\int@op\limits}\int@test}
\def\int@catchsub_#1{\expandafter\def\expandafter\int@op\expandafter{\int@op_{#1}}\int@test}
\def\int@catchsup^#1{\expandafter\def\expandafter\int@op\expandafter{\int@op^{#1}}\int@test}
\def\int@print#1\dif#2{%
        \ifx\int@opt\@empty
            \int@op
        \else
            \ifx\int@opt\int@arg
                \expandafter\smashoperator\expandafter{\int@op}%
            \else
                \expandafter\smashoperator\expandafter[\expandafter\int@opt\expandafter]\expandafter{\int@op}%
            \fi
        \fi
        #1 \, \@firstofone{\dif}#2%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int_1^{10} \int_{\{u = t\}} \vert\nabla u \vert \dif \sigma \dif t
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually the pairing of `\int` and `\dif` is wrong in case of nesting integrals when doing things in terms of delimited arguments, but this in some situations probably won't affect the visual output.

However, there is no way to automatically detect whether a token `\dif` delimits the argument of an integral or is a component of the argument of an integral, so there will be situations where you cannot get away without hiding `\dif` which do not delimit the argument of an integral between `{...}` or `\firstofone{...}`.

I did some guessing regarding documentclass/preamble in use etc.
Better you provide a [**Minimal Reproducible Example**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which people can copy-paste to new file and compile for reproducing the output you get without the need of doing guesswork and editing.

Comment: This is not the exact solution but at least it does the job. I was wondering whether there is a way to create a `\left`-`\right` macro syntax, but I guess it is more complicated.

Comment: With `\left`-`\right` it is assumed that each  `\left`/`\right` has a matching counterpart. But - depending on the context - a `\dif` might not be the matching counterpart of an `\int` although being component of the argument of an `\int`.

Answer (score 6):

The usual way is to use a `\mathop` here to let TeX add space or not depending on the previous item

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\dif{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int_1^{10} \int_{\{u = t\}} \vert\nabla u \vert \dif \sigma \dif t
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Or, if you *really* must, with an upright d

```
\newcommand\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to keep the `\dif` macro without space.

Comment: @LucaBenatti in the rare case you want no space but `\mathop` adds one, you can use `{\dif t}` and will get no space.  Impossible to comment  more on your code unless you provide an example